# Identify users device

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, dynamic, subscriber, custom-url

Is it possible to identify the device which is using each subscriber and store that info as a variable with a value, and after use that value to do something like the example below?

```
%%[set @myvariable = concat('http://www.example.com/?campaign=', CampaignCode)]%%
    <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@myvariable)=%%">My Link<>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the use case? By identifying - do you mean the user-agent string? And is this within an email or on a cloud page? Or do you want to set a cookie on user’s device for later recognition?

Comment: As a note, if it is in an email, you cannot use the user-agent string because that is collected at receipt, not sending - so it is after the server side code has already been compiled and completed. You would only be able to use historic data stored in a DE or CSS to manipulate content based on device for emails.

Comment: @LukasLunow, in our website, when the user wants to make a reservation, a key is granted, depends on the device, (desktop or mobile), this key serves as a filter to send users to the desktop or responsive booking engine. I want to use this feature within the email links, with the data stored in CSS about screen size in order to assign a string value in the button link when is clicked.

Comment: This is an example for a booking engine link: https://reservaciones.granplan.com/Paquetes/Lista?&Af=granplanmx0&cu=PE&ln=ESP&no=Ciudad de México (MEX) Aeropuerto Internacional Benito Juárez, México&ni=Riviera Nayarit, México - Aeropuerto Gustavo Díaz Ordaz (PVR)&sd=12/08/2019&ed=14/08/2019&rm=1&ad1=2&ch1=0&ob=mex&ib=PVR&ds=112&hpa=1&ht=4768 .   The key value here is "granplanmx0", that would have to be the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it has been pointed out in the comments already, it is not possible to do anything within the email itself, as this has been compiled at send-time - not knowing about the device on which the email will be opened.

I have built similar solutions before, where I have used following approach:

1. Two versions of the website, e.g.: responsive.example.com and desktop.example.com
2. A redirect page, built in e.g. PHP, detecting the user-agent, and redirects to either responsive or desktop within milliseconds
3. A link in your email, pointing to #2

Ensure, that the redirect built in #2 keeps all the request parameters from the original link in email. Hence you will maintain e.g. utm parameters all the way to your final destination. You can use e.g. http://www.apachemobilefilter.org/ as a basis for detecting and redirecting.